# What happens to the bodies of immortals after they have been beheaded?

Tags: highlander-franchise

In the highlander series, particularly the TV show, it never really talks about what happens to the bodies of the immortals who have been decapitated.  We know what happens to the victor, they absorb the quickening from their defeated foe, but there are many instances where after the quickening has been absorbed a body is left behind.

In Highlander, season 3, episode 8 titled "The Lamb," shortly after the child immortal had snuck up on and killed the immortal that had been pursuing him, Duncan returns to find the child immortal gone and the body of the deceased immortal lying on the ground.  I know this is not the only instance where a corpse remains after the quickening has been absorbed.

I am curious just because of the plot holes a bunch of decapitated corpses could bring about, especially with Duncan's girlfriend being a doctor at the hospital.  She could potentially recognize the decapitated body of a man her boyfriend Duncan had an argument with a couple nights before.

After a series of decapitations, the police would definitely be more open-eyed to a serial killer who has a habit of getting a head in life.

In short, I am just curious what happens to the bodies.

Comment: Nothing happens to them. The police are very interested to see that decapitated bodies are turning up all over the place

Comment: In the interrogation scene in the first (and only) movie, the police mentions two decapitated persons (Vasilek and Fasil), so apparently nothing special happens to the bodies. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_xQoRtoQpg

Comment: This may not be correct but I recall it was shown that the Watchers had a sword collection and would imply they cleaned up some of the crime scenes.

Answer (score 4):

Duncan's [girlfriend](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/Anne_Lindsey) is a trauma surgeon. When someone's had their head chopped off, they don't usually get taken to the Emergency Room, they get certified as dead at the scene and taken to the coroner.

It would be highly unlikely that she'd encounter anyone that he successfully fought in her line of work. What's she gonna do, stick their head back on with surgical tape and hope for the best?

---

As to what's happening to the bodies, the simple fact is that the police *are* catching them, but can't work out the motive for the murders because the motive eludes them and the immortals are pretty good at not getting caught. They think there's a single killer instead of a fight-club.

> **Randi:** *You know, I was thinking about what you said yesterday about history repeating itself. I spent the last twenty-four hours in
> the archives running down old serial murder cases.*
>
> **Duncan:** *You did?*
>
> **Randi:** *There is one that fits the pattern. It happened sixty-seven years ago, MacLeod. How'd you know about it?*
>
> <sub><sup>*Highlander: See No Evil*</sup></sub>

Answer (score -2):

This problem of 'plot holes' is poorly handled initially by the writers. As a result, one would think after a few seasons of a decapitation per week, it would become a keen interest to Interpol, enough for the basis of a spinoff from Interpol's viewpoint!

In one episode sometime in, I think, the second season the headless body is levitated. About this time forensic interest drops off almost altogether.

MY solution is that the same force that heals them (but why isn't Kalas' throat injury not healed? One COULD say once a body part is severed, it loses the quickening force, as with Xavier St. Cloud, but that doesn't solve Kalas' injury), the quickening, also keeps it from decomposing to its natural state. So, when Darius dies, his body returns to the condition of a centuries old corpse, leaving the questions to the archeological forensic investigators. In fact, due to the myriad number of fractures sustained and healed over centuries, even the bones would lose their integrity, leaving dessicated piles of calcium dressed in contemporary clothes. Interesting grist for a forensic tailor perhaps, but insufficient blood (also now completely decomposed) to conclude any crime was committed. Indeed  the only crime is grime, dirty clothes lying about after humongous electrical events destroying vast sections of property and even Paris' infrastructure. Imagine the business computer importers had after Mac used the Eiffel Tower as "the world's biggest lightning arrestor"!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence for this?  This seems like your personal theory, but you need to give an answer based on what is depicted in the show.